# Steam voice chat is not working

Tags: steam

My friend has been with me and my other friends on Steam for a while. We would always hang out and talk with each other. But one day, his Steam group chat and VC stopped working. We went through the normal troubleshooting, but to no avail. He can enter the group chat, but it never registers as being "active". In his own words "I can enter the group chat, but when I try to use the voice chat, nothing happens."

He tried another Mic on the same computer, and it did not work with Steam. He used the same Mic on Skype, and it works perfectly fine. He used the same Mic on a different computer , and it worked properly. Recently, he did a factory default on his computer, and re-installed Steam. this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Try to go in steam and look in settings. Voice chat might be disabled or maybe a Steam update that you might need to enable some settings.

Comment: I need some information... What you mean with nothing happens? Is it possible to start the voice chat and he is able to see the peakmeter of the input and output (it could be red, it should be white) or not? Can you just not hear his voice?

Comment: Dunno what is your problem, but if you can, don't use steam voice chat. Use skype/teamspeak etc. Even when the voice chat works, it is buggy as hell.

Comment: One day it started working out of no where. @Gerret, it did not get a red slash, but steam would not pick it up. We still do not know what fixed it or caused it.